# PWA and SPA support in Apple Watch

Tags: single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, apple-watch

I was wondering if there is a complete documentation for creating PWA and SPA Web Applications which could be added/installed to Apple Watch

I mean a web application which has manifest(name, icon, etc) and can be added to Apple Watch menu

As of WatchOS 5, Apple have added webkit support to WatchOS and i guess it’s not a deal to render web pages because there are several web browsers for Apple Watch like parity and etc

I would be happy to hear your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make a PWA or SPA as an app on mobile platform is to use a framework that uses the webview component of the platform to show the content as it was a native app.

Unfortunately [1] my source about a cordova apple watch plugin says, that

> It is not possible to run a Cordova app directly on the Watch, as there is no support for a WebView [..]

Though, the source [1] is a project that gives some help on communicating between iPhone app and the Watch, but as the solution here is to write the showing of the data on native language anyways, I would probably more likely give a try for Xamarin [2] or any other native code generating framework, which DOES support Watch OS. I think your final goal anyways is to write an app for Watch, so that is the way to do so.

**My source:**

[1] https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/